# How to access .shp file from local computer or some other server

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, api

Below is the code in which we can access a feature layer from ArcGIS sample server.

```
queryTask = new esri.arcgis.gmaps.QueryTask("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/3");
```

But I want to access my own .shp file residing on my local computer or on another server, e.g this..

```
queryTask = new esri.arcgis.gmaps.QueryTask("http://172.20.100.12/Demo/Resources/ABC.shp");
```

In this case, queryTask does not return featureSet and so .shp file could not display on Map.

Where is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Autodesk has an open url technology. But ESRI hasn't ever supported that.

Answer (score 1):

From the structure of your code, it seems that your query expects to connect to a rest/georest server in order to obtain the map you would like it to display. If your could accept direct connection to a shapefile, then you would only need to host it on a webserver and point to it (just like you are already trying to do), but that does not seem to be the case. It looks like you will need to setup a georest server where you can load the shapefiles you would like to serve and only then reconstruct the query pointing to where this loaded map is being served.

I think your code is expecting you to setup and use arcgis server; but there are several free alternatives like mapserver and geoserver. Personally, I go with geoserver - take a look at http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/ for instructions as to how to install and load maps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually i want to access shapefiles form our web server 172.20.100.12/Demo as you see from code. But I dont know how to point to it and how i can access featureSet. Can u help me what should i do ? I dont want to setup georest server for this purpose.

Comment: Is your code part of the google maps api that esri provides? If that is the case, there is no way of serving a shapefile pointing directly to it. If you just want to have access to the raw .shp file -- to use in arcmap, for example --, create a shared directory on the network if it is a local network; or setup a vpn for a remote connection.

Comment: I have downloaded and installed geoserver and publish one shapefile. Now how can i access that shapefile to use its featureSet ? From Esri sample server we access the file by using following code:  queryTask = new esri.arcgis.gmaps.QueryTask("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/3");

Similarly like code above, which piece of code i use to access .shp file from geoserver ?

Comment: @user1899, if you go into the demo section of geoserver's administration web page, you can see examples of links to multiple services that you can use. Note that the rest service is only installed by default if you have the latest release candidate. Otherwise, you will need to install the rest plugin to make the same type of query you have been doing.

Comment: Thanks again, You mean I have to use this(http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs) line of code in place of ("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/3"); am i right ?

Comment: If the api allows for wfs; it would be more common for it to accept wms. Your original source was pointing to "rest"; to install rest support on geoserver you need a special plugin; but see if you can make it work with wms or wfs

Comment: How can i check either the Rest plugin is installed or not ? and with the Rest plugin, can i use this code: queryTask = new esri.arcgis.gmaps.QueryTask("http://(localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs");

Comment: http://docs.geoserver.org/2.0.0/user/extensions/rest/index.html will guide you through the rest plugin; wfs is different protocol; there are several protocols for connection; the one you were using is rest - which comes with arcgis server - geoserver can do rest, but wms and wfs are its standards by default.

Comment: How can i get the URL of my resource published at geoserver ? I want to use that URL with ArcGIS API application.

Comment: I have downloaded and installed GeoServer 2.1-RC1 which shipped with RESTconfig. How can i check whether REST service is installed with GeoServer or Not ? 

I put this "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest" in my browser, but it gives error! ... It means REST service is not installed as i understand. Or is there any other method to check whether the service is installed or not ? 
Secondly how i publish my data using REST service on Geoserver ?