# Using REST service with GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, rest

I have downloaded and installed GeoServer 2.1-RC1 which shipped with RESTconfig. How can i check whether REST service is installed with GeoServer or Not ?

I put this "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest" in my browser, but it gives error! ... It means REST service is not installed as i understand. Or is there any other method to check whether the service is installed or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[purpose of this project is to hold a REST client library to interact with GeoServer](http://code.google.com/p/geoserver-manager/)

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried any of the configuration examples in the docs ([here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/restconfig/rest-config-examples-curl.html))?

You can access layer information through e.g. http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/giant_polygon.html

Publishing a shapefile works like this:

Consider a directory on the server /data/shapefiles/roads that contains the Shapefile roads.shp. The following adds a new datastore for the Shapefile:

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H 'Content-type: text/plain' \
-d 'file:///data/shapefiles/roads/roads.shp' \
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/acme/datastores/roads/external.shp
```

Source: [Geoserver REST Docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/restconfig/rest-config-examples-curl.html) (Also describes how to add a PostGIS layer.)

Comment: Actually i want to know, How i publish my data

Comment: Please explain which step is causing you troubles. Have you checked http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/gettingstarted/index.html?

Comment: Actually i want to know, How i publish my data by using REST service. because My data is published by Geoserver default protocols wfs or wms. I can see wms, wfs and wcs services on geoserver web page services section at http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/. But i could not see REST any where. How can i see REST or can check wether its available or not?

Comment: Have you tried something like http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/giant_polygon.html?

Comment: Thanks for replying!. I got following reply: Layer "giant_polygon" 
Name: giant_polygon 
Default style: StyleInfoImpl[giant_polygon] 
Available styles: [] 
Now please explain how i publish my data by REST service on Geoserver ?

Comment: Do you mean: a) How to upload a file to Geoserver using REST? or b) How to consume a file published via Geoserver using REST?

Comment: Yes. I need both a) and b) as you said. Please also explain, How ArcGIS API for javascript client will access the published data from Geoserver? We can query data to ArcGIS Sampleserver by using code as: queryTask = new
esri.arcgis.gmaps.QueryTask("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/3");

Comment: Yes. I need both a) and b) as you said. Please also explain, How ArcGIS API for javascript client will access the published data from Geoserver? e.g, We can query data to ArcGIS Sampleserver by using code as: queryTask = new esri.arcgis.gmaps.QueryTask("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/3"); What URL string should i use in the the above line of code? Is this URL (localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/giant_polygon.html) valid ? suppose if want to query giant_polygon.

Comment: ad a) See my updated answer. ad b) Are you referring to this QueryTask: http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples/query_nomap.html?

Comment: Yes exactly, so what URL should i use instead of ("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/5"); URL ?

Comment: I doubt that it is possible to get ArcGIS Javascript API to work with Geoserver using REST. Why not use something standardized like WMS? http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples/layers_wms.html

Comment: As I mentioned on another question, ArcGIS Javascript API expects an Arcgis server -- I can't be sure that any other free alternative implements rest in the exact same way that ArcGIS server does. Please refer to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/771/what-are-some-web-based-clients-for-geoserver for a list of alternative APIs.

Comment: I have posted my question in this forum 6 days ago and one of the user of this forum advised me that you can use Geoserver with ArcGIS API for javescript (because i dont have ArcGIS Server). By Using Geoserver with REST, we can make same type of query as in ArcGIS case. further u can check this post: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5905/how-to-access-shp-file-from-local-computer-or-some-other-server