# Geoserver Rest folder not found

Tags: geoserver

I am trying to learn geoserver's rest-api following http://docs.geoserver.org/2.0.x/en/user/extensions/rest/index.html.

I have placed rest-2.0.3 jar file in geoserver/webmaps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib folder and restarted the server. I don't know whether this completes the installation of rest.

All the examples in curl rest shows the path as *http://localhost/geoserver/rest/workspaces..... but I am not able to find any rest folder and the link *http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest giving me the page with "Geoserver Configuration API" .

I have followed [Using REST service with GeoServer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/using-rest-service-with-geoserver) but even this doesn't solve my problem.

Can you please tell me how to find whether rest is installed or not.... *http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/giant_polygon.html also giving me "Geoserver Configuration API".

Comment: are you using version 2.0.3? If you use 2.1 then Rest is built in so there is no need to add the plugin.

Comment: Use Geoserver 2.1 REST is built in as iant mentions

Comment: @iant, installing 2.1.0 is working fine. I can see all the workspaces at http://localhost:8081/geoserver/rest/workspaces . But When I try to create a workspace following http://docs.geoserver.org/2.0.x/en/user/extensions/rest/rest-config-examples-curl.html the curl command tool is giving me "the system cannot find the file specified".  Where am I going wrong??? Is there any relation btw the curl path and geoserver path?? I think there shouldn't be any. I am running curl from C:/windows/system32/curl

Comment: It sounds like curl is not installed properly, I can't really help I've never used it in windows.

Comment: @VikashTalanki How did you install cURL btw?